# how to decode h264 byte[] to BufferedImage [Java]

Tags: java, h.264, jcodec

I am receiving a `byte[]` for every frame of a video stream and want to decode it to a BufferedImage using JCodec library.
This is my code:

```
private H264Decoder decoder = new H264Decoder();
private ByteBuffer bb = null;
private Picture out = Picture.create(960, 720, ColorSpace.YUV420);
private void decode(byte[] data) {
    System.out.println("decoding");
    bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
    Picture real = decoder.decodeFrame(bb, out.getData());
    BufferedImage bi = AWTUtil.toBufferedImage(real);
}
```

But this is the error message I get when I call the decode() method:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jcodec.scale.AWTUtil.toBufferedImage(AWTUtil.java:28)
at TelloCameraThread.decode(TelloCameraThread.java:88)
at TelloCameraThread.run(TelloCameraThread.java:62)
```

Does anyone see the mistake I'm making or have alternative ideas to achieve my goal?

Help appreciated.

nvplus

Comment: in debugging mode, check if `Picture real` is null or not.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov Yes, `Picture real = null`. But now I'm wondering why `decoder.decodeFrame(bb, out.getData())` does return `null`.

Comment: in debugger, trace the execution of the `decoder.decodeFrame`.

Comment: is `ByteBuffer bb` still null?

Comment: `ByteBuffer bb` is not null

Comment: but I've noticed there is a second error in my program: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:708)
 at maintellotest.main(maintellotest.java:28)` It gets thrown before the other error.

Comment: looks like you are trying to start already started thread.

Comment: oh, yeah. I fixed that issue. But the `NullPointerException` stays. I think there got to be a mistake in the library or I am just to stupid to use it in the correct way. But thanks for your help @AlexeiKaigorodov

Comment: the best thank is to upvote comments.